# Does gender transitioning do nothing to help suicidal ideation?

Tags: gender, psychiatry, suicide, lgbt, surgery

According to the article [A landmark Finnish study is changing how we approach transgender kids](https://nypost.com/2024/02/24/opinion/a-finnish-study-is-changing-how-we-approach-trans-kids/):

> A major new study out of Finland found that providing cross-sex hormones and gender-transition surgeries to adolescents and young adults didn’t appear to have any significant effect on suicide deaths.

They are referring to the study [All-cause and suicide mortalities among adolescents and young adults who contacted specialised gender identity services in Finland in 1996–2019](https://mentalhealth.bmj.com/content/27/1/e300940.full).

Is it true that gender transitioning has no effect on suicidal ideation?

Comment: The quote is talking about suicide **deaths**, but the question asks about suicide **ideation**. Those are very different things. You should either adjust the question to match the quote, or find a quote that makes a claim about ideation.

Comment: @IMSoP The paper says "[medical gender reassignment] has also not been shown to reduce even suicidal ideation, and suicidal ideation is not equal to actual suicide risk". However, I'm not sure if OP is interested in answers about suicide ideation or deaths.